# Modeling lookup data

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Quick question on modeling data for a customer …

- Customer stores Store data, about 250 records, maybe 10 properties each.
- Customer stores Department data, about 1,000 record, again, maybe 10 properties each.
- Customer stores Product data, about 2,000,000 records, maybe 20 properties each.

My thoughts for modeling this data, based on how it is accessed is to store Store data and Department data in a `lookups` collection, partitioned on the `object` property, in this case, Store of Department.

Store the Product data in a `products` collection, partitioned on the `upc_code` property.

Does this make sense? Or is there a better way, specifically with handling small (< 1,000 records) datasets, should I recommend Table Storage for any of this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your data access patterns have a lot more to do with how you partition and store data in Cosmos than the relationships. Any answers would be opinion based. If you haven't already, maybe [start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-cases)

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder, I did take a look at that article. Specifically looking for geared more towards lookups, e.g. key/value data. Is there something specific in that article that I overlooked, please let me know!

Comment: Also, for those down-voting this question, please keep in mind that right or wrong, this is the recommended path for getting support on `azure-cosmosdb` from the Cosmos product team.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that could work. I wouldn't use the Table API for this though. If you want key/value features use SQL API and turn off indexing. But only if you look up product by upc_code.

Another question. Is this data all related? Have you looked at possibly storing this as a graph and using the Gremlin API in Cosmos?

Comment: Thanks @Mark Brown, it is related, but very loosely, again, just lookup data ... I looked at Gremlin, but thought it would probably be overkill. Good recommendation on the turning off indexing, I will look at that.